# All Backbone models being initialized using RequireJS

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I have a backbone/marionette project structured with requirejs.

```
define([
  'views/FormView',
  'path/to/Model',
], function (FormView, Model) {
  "use strict";

  return FormView.extend({

    model: new Model(),

    /* --- rest of view stuff --- */

  });
});
```

All the models in the project are being initialized (ie, initialize() will be called on all the models) when the page loads, but the views are only being initialized when they are instantiated by the controller.

The models should only be initalized once they are instantiated, and it's causing me a number of headaches.

Has anyone encountered this before?

**Update:**

thanks to Kevin and Yura for their answers, this code works:

```
define([
  'views/FormView',
  'path/to/Model',
], function (FormView, Model) {
  "use strict";

  return FormView.extend({

    model: undefined,

    initialize: function () {
      this.model = new Model();
    }

    /* --- rest of view stuff --- */

  });
});
```

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: mafoo, defining an "undefined" property `model` is a good idea, as you did in the update. It definitely makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that

```
model: new Model()
```

runs as soon as this requirejs module is loaded into the browser. That is, when it is required, it returns the extended `FormView`, and that prototype is used for all instances of `FormView`.

At this time new instance object of `Model` is instantiated and that same instance is used as the `model` property of every new instance of `FormView`.

What you can do is instead of extending your `FormView` with the `model` property directly, delegate that `model` instance creation to initialization of the `FormView` instance:

```
define([
 'views/FormView',
 'path/to/Model', 
], function (FormView, Model) {   "use strict";

  return FormView.extend({

    initialize: function(){
      /* Create property `model` whenever new instance of FormView is created */
      this.model = new Model();
    }

    /* --- rest of view stuff --- */

  });
});
```

Here's complete working example to show the difference:

```js
/** EXAMPLE 1 **
  Directly extending with `model` property and assigning 
  new instance of `Model`. Later you find out same model 
  instance is used for all `MyView` instances.
*/
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  model: new Backbone.Model(),
  render: function(){
    this.$el.text('I am ' + this.model.get('name'));
  }
});

var myView1 = new MyView();
myView1.$el.appendTo(document.body);
var myView2 = new MyView();
myView2.$el.appendTo(document.body);

myView1.model.set({name: "Joe"});
myView2.model.set({name: "Bob"});

myView1.render();
myView2.render();

/** EXAMPLE 2 **
  Extending with `model` in initialize will create and assign
  new instance of `model` every time `MyOtherView` instance is created.
*/
var MyOtherView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.model = new Backbone.Model();
  },
  render: function(){
    this.$el.text('I am ' + this.model.get('name'));
  }
});

var myView1 = new MyOtherView();
myView1.$el.appendTo(document.body);
var myView2 = new MyOtherView();
myView2.$el.appendTo(document.body);

myView1.model.set({name: "Alice"});
myView2.model.set({name: "Catrine"});

myView1.render();
myView2.render();
```

```html
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js'></script>
<script src='http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js'></script>
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion of using the initialize fuction after reading Kevin's response.

Answer (score 0):

*The models should only be initalized once they are instantiated*

They will be, by definition.

You're instantiating the model in the class definition above, so its initializer runs when the `FormView` code is defined. What you probably want to do is pass the model as an option when you create the view in your controller, e.g.:

```
var my_model = new Model();
var my_view = new FormView({model: my_model});
```